# 2D associative array. 2 hash don't work

Tags: ruby

```
t = Hash.new { Hash.new }
t['x']['y'] = 1
print "#{t['x']['y']}"
```

`print "#{t['x']['y']}` produces nothing, why..? I just want 2d associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It produces nothing because providing the default value in the case of a key that isn't present does *not* modify the hash, per the following documentation fragment from http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new

> If a block is specified, it will be called with the hash object and
>   the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s
>   responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

To get the effect you're looking for, you'd need to do:

```
t = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new}
```